# crystal reports with parameters at runtime

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to apply a project (http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/pass-parameters-to-crystal-reports-in.html) on my website. I only get whatever value I choose for the first time and get the required report but if I select other values then again I get the report previous report. Can anybody help me?

default.aspx.cs

```cs
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
    reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
    reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", "ghaffar-pc", "Northwind");
    //reportdocument.SetParameterValue("Username", txtUserName.Text);
    reportdocument.SetParameterValue("CategoryID", Convert.ToInt32(txtUserName.Text));
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
}
```

Default.aspx

```html
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Enter UserName</b></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="btnSearch_Click" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</div>
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
    EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" AutoDataBind="true" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="False"
    EnableParameterPrompt="False" ToolPanelView="None" />
```

Please note I get the required result in CrystalReport.rpt file whatever value I select to display the report.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
reportdocument.Refresh();
```

just above following stmt.

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
reportdocument.SetParameterValue("CategoryID", Convert.ToInt32(txtUserName.Text));
```

add this:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo.Clear();
```